# How does formality in a therapy relationship effect treatment outcomes?

Tags: therapy

Languages like German and French have two different you. German has "du and sie" while French has "tu and vous".
It's common in therapy contexts to use the more formal version "sie"/"vous". Is there research that indicates that using the more formal pronoun increases the likelihood of treatment success?